# Can't find a solution for array reverse algorithm problem

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, reverse

I have a requirement where I have to reverse an array without changing the index of '#' presents in an array, like below example:

- Array `[18,-4,'#',0,8,'#',5]` should return `[5, 8, "#", 0, -4, "#", 18]`, here numbers should be reversed, excluding '#' while keeping the same index.

I have tried to get the correct output, but it doesn't seem to be correct in all scenarios:
var arr = [18,-4,'#',0,8,'#',5]; // giving result is correct
var arr1 = [18,-4,0,'#',8,'#',5]; // result is not correct

```js
var reverse = function(numbers, start, end){
 var temp = numbers[start];
  numbers[start] = numbers[end];
  numbers[end] = temp;
}
var flip = function(numbers) {
var start = 0;
var end = numbers.length-1;
 for(var i=0;i<parseInt(numbers.length/2);i++) {
   if(numbers[i] === '#') {
     start = i+1;
      end = numbers.length - i - i;
      reverse(numbers, start, end);
    } else if (numbers[numbers.length - i - 1] === '#') {
     start = i;
      end = numbers.length - i - 2;
      reverse(numbers, start, end);
    } else {
     reverse(numbers, start, end);
    }
  }
  return numbers;
}

var arr = [18,-4,'#',0,8,'#',5];
var arr1 = [18,-4,0,'#',8,'#',5];
console.log(flip(arr));
console.log(flip(arr1));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simplify the function and use only two indices, the start and end and check if the value at the indices should stay, then choose another index for swapping.

```js
const
    swap = (array, a, b) => [array[a], array[b]] = [array[b], array[a]],
    flip = numbers => {
        var start = 0,
            end = numbers.length - 1;

        while (start < end) {
            if (numbers[start] === '#') {
                start++;
                continue;
            }
            if (numbers[end] === '#') {
                end--;
                continue;
            }
            swap(numbers, start++, end--);
        }
        return numbers;
    },
    array1 = [18, -4, '#', 0, 8, '#', 5],
    array2 = [18, -4, 0, '#', 8, '#', 5];

console.log(...flip(array1));
console.log(...flip(array2));
```

Answer (score 2):

The trivial approach would be to remove all `'#'`'s, reverse the array using the built in `[].reverse` method, and then re-insert the `'#'`'s:

```js
let flip = numbers => {
  let removed = numbers.reduce((r, v, i) =>
          v === '#' ? r.concat(i) : r
      , []);

  let reversed = numbers.filter(v => v !== '#').reverse();

  removed.forEach(i => reversed.splice(i, 0, '#'));

  return reversed;
};

let arr = [18, -4, '#', 0, 8, '#', 5];
let arr1 = [18, -4, 0, '#', 8, '#', 5];
console.log(flip(arr));
console.log(flip(arr1));
```

Comment: Thanks, @junvar for the efforts, but I need it without predefined functions, I want to use basic logics of loop or something, can it be simplified ?

Comment: @SarveshMahajan: Unless this is homework, or you have some really serious performance constraints, I would suggest that using `filter`, `concat`, `reduce`, etc. makes for more easily readable code than custom loops.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```js
var numbers = arr.filter(a => a !== '#')
var revArr = [];
arr.forEach((currentValue) => {
    if(currentValue !== "#") {
        revArr.push(numbers.pop());
    } else {
        revArr.push("#");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, @sagar for your efforts, can it be simplified without filters?

Answer (score 1):

You can base your algorithm on two basic array (array of reversed numbers and and an array with "#" saved positions)

```js
const array = [5, 8, "#", 0, -4, "#", 18];

function flip(array) {

  const arrayNumbers = array.filter((el, index) => el !== "#").reverse();

  var counter = 0;

  return array.map(el => el === "#").map(el => {
    if (!el) {
      let num = arrayNumbers[counter];
      counter = counter + 1;
      return num;
    } else {
      return "#"
    }
  })
}

console.log(flip(array));
```

Comment: Note that the question asked for a `reverse`, not a `sort`

Comment: Thanks @G.aziz for your efforts, but I need to implement it without filters, can it be simplified ?

Comment: @SarveshMahajan: replacing the `filter` and `map` with custom loops would be the opposite of simplifying.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [18,-4,'#',0,8,'#',5]
var stack = []

for (i=0 ; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == '#') continue;
    stack.push(arr[i]);
}

for (i=0 ; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] != '#') {
        arr[i] = stack.pop();
    }
}

console.log(arr)
```

The above code should solve your problem.

The implementation uses stack where we keep inserting elements into stack untill we see a '#' and skip it.
While creating the output array we refer the original array for '#' index and stack for reverse index.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
        int end = v.length - 1;
        int start = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < v.length >> 1; i++) {
            if (v[start].equals("#")) {
                start++;
                continue;
            }
            if (v[end].equals("#")) {
                end--;
                continue;
            }
            Object temp = v[end];
            v[end] = v[start];
            v[start] = temp;
            end--;
            start++;

        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(v));
```

Comment: Perhaps now, but not earlier.  The OP changed the tag.